# Ink / formulation chemistry: What lab requirements

Tags: experimental-chemistry, solutions, reference-request

Little open information can be found on the requirements of the *manufacture, development and testing* of **gel and printing inks**. 
It seems that most ink manufacturers have their own specific lab configuration.

Would you know of a recource, or could you list me a possible lab setup for such an endeveavor? While I have found books on the topic, few of them are of very practical nature.

Of specific interest to me are

- analytic methods
- synthetic apparatus
- testing procedures and protocols

Thank you very much!